# Anime with summoned mecha beasts, "teslajoules" and possibly a beast named Dragoon. Seen between 2009-2013

Tags: story-identification, anime

The anime was set in another world with summoned mecha beasts. The words "teslajoules" are often used. The main character has a mecha beast named "Dragoon". I saw it between 2009-2013.

Comment: This is a bit sparse. I recommend visiting [this Meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and more specifically [this one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) to find prompts to [edit] in more details. Like what was the animation style like? Were the characters caucasian? Bestial? Teenagers? Pensioners? How violent was it? Any sexual content?

Comment: Dragoon reminds me of the first generation of Beyblade where the protagonist had a *top* (to use normal language) out of which, when called upon a *beast* (it looks like a mecha to several people the first time they see it) like mentioned in the OP comes out, although I have majority of the episodes of the series, I don't remember "teslajoules". I googled it, and the next generation of the series came out in 2010, which seems about right a time to see the earlier series. @AnubhavDas, do you remember any tops? Or anything that spins, in general?

Comment: Also, how was the video quality of the show? If you can give us an estimate, it would be easier to understand what year the anime was released, and we can filter the possible answers accordingly.

Comment: I can't find any hits on "teslajoule" anywhere that aren't a username or garbage SEO text.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the anime you are looking for is *Beyblade - Season 1*?

> Beyblade is a 2001 Japanese anime television series based on Takao Aoki's manga series of the same name, which itself is based on the Beyblade spinning top game from Takara Tomy. The 51-episode series was produced by Madhouse under the direction of Toshifumi Kawase.
>
> The series was first broadcast on TV Tokyo in Japan from January 8 to December 24, 2001. The season was licensed for English adaptation, broadcast, and release by Nelvana. The series was broadcast on the sibling cable channel YTV in Canada and ABC Family in the United States in 2002.*

[From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyblade_(season_1))]

The seasons in *Beyblade* are also divided up into generations based on the content, protagonists, quality of video (compared to anime produced today) and many more things. Season 1 of *Beyblade* comes under Generation 1. It features the characters using tops that are made of Plastic, and thus Generation 1 is also called Plastic Generation.

Trailer for Beyblade Generation 1:

Another reason why I think it is this anime that the OP is looking for is because the protagonist of the series carries a Beyblade which when spun, and the called upon, a beast-like thing called Dragoon came out.

Season 1 stopped airing in 2004, because Beyblade, at the time, was losing popularity, and thus its airing was stopped so Takara could focus mainly on its toy line of Beyblade products.

However, when Beyblade Metal Fight (Season 2) came out with better video quality, better storylines and other things, interest in Beyblade was reawakened. Season 2 came out in 2010, and it was at the same time that Season 1 was also being aired again in several places owing to its increasing popularity. It is very likely that the OP saw a re-airing of Season 1 because of the reason mentioned before.

I have seen several episodes of this series, but I never came across anything like "teslajoules". A Google search also doesn't reveal anything that looks like it is related to this anime, or any other for that matter.

As @Valorum has pointed out in a comment below. "Joule" is the name of a character from this series.

Comment: joule is the name of a character...